# stat command with formatted string argument in Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, command-line-arguments

I want to pass string variable of some files (example: `'file1\nfile2\nfile3'`) as an argument for `stat` command in Linux. Actually, I know about `stat file1 file2 file3`, but I want to pass **format** string with `\n`. Thanks.

Comment: *"Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question."*

Comment: Execute `man stat` or check  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html for an argument list. But my guess is in the answer, hope it helps :)

Comment: You might also try https://unix.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to execute `stat` from `xargs` instead since the `stat` command only accepts one or more files (But not any formatted string)

For example, what you could do is the following:

`echo -e "file1\nfile2\nfile3\nmydir" | xargs stat`